# How can I calculate/find the week-number of a given date?

Tags: c#, asp.net, date

How can I calculate/find the week-number of a given date?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
var currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
var weekNo = currentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
                new DateTime(2013, 12, 31),
                currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
                currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
```

Be aware that this is **not** [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Week_dates) compatible. In Sweden we use ISO 8601 [week](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear.aspx) numbers but even though the culture is set to "sv-SE", `CalendarWeekRule` is `FirstFourDayWeek`, and `FirstDayOfWeek` is Monday the *weekNo* variable will be set to **53** instead of the correct **1** in the above code.

I have only tried this with Swedish settings but I'm pretty sure that all countries (Austria, Germany, Switzerland and more) using ISO 8601 week numbers will be affected by this problem.

[Peter van Ooijen](http://codebetter.com/blogs/peter.van.ooijen/archive/2005/09/26/132466.aspx) and [Shawn Steele](http://blogs.msdn.com/shawnste/archive/2006/01/24/iso-8601-week-of-year-format-in-microsoft-net.aspx) has different solutions to this problem.

Here's a compact solution

```
private static int WeekOfYearISO8601(DateTime date)
{
    var day = (int)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetDayOfWeek(date);
    return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date.AddDays(4 - (day == 0 ? 7 : day)), CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
}
```

It's been tested for the following dates

```
var datesAndISO8601Weeks = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>
                        {
                            {new DateTime(2000, 12, 31), 52},
                            {new DateTime(2001, 1, 1), 1},
                            {new DateTime(2005, 1, 1), 53},
                            {new DateTime(2007, 12, 31), 1},
                            {new DateTime(2008, 12, 29), 1},
                            {new DateTime(2010, 1, 3), 53},
                            {new DateTime(2011, 12, 31), 52},
                            {new DateTime(2012, 1, 1), 52},
                            {new DateTime(2013, 1, 2), 1},
                            {new DateTime(2013, 12, 31), 1},
                        };

foreach (var dateWeek in datesAndISO8601Weeks)
{
    Debug.Assert(WeekOfYearISO8601(dateWeek.Key) == dateWeek.Value, dateWeek.Key.ToShortDateString() + " should be week number " + dateWeek.Value + " but was " + WeekOfYearISO8601(dateWeek.Key));
}
```

Comment: same problem with the rest of scandinavia I think, I'm danish and I was wondering why my tests showed 31/12 to be week #53 too as my Google Calender states its week #1.

Comment: why using "var" everywhere?

Comment: Because it's easier to read and less repetitive than

`Dictionary<DateTime, int> datesAndISO8601Weeks = new Dictionary<DateTime, int>();`
The reason I do it for simple types is that it keeps the code consistent.

Comment: Can also add that using var forces you to choose good variable names.

Answer (score 5):

```
  public static int GetWeekNumber(DateTime dtPassed)
  {
          CultureInfo ciCurr = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
          int weekNum = ciCurr.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(dtPassed, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFourDayWeek, DayOfWeek.Monday);
          return weekNum;
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Check out [GetWeekOfYear](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.getweekofyear.aspx) on MSDN has this example:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;


public class SamplesCalendar  {

   public static void Main()  {

      // Gets the Calendar instance associated with a CultureInfo.
      CultureInfo myCI = new CultureInfo("en-US");
      Calendar myCal = myCI.Calendar;

      // Gets the DTFI properties required by GetWeekOfYear.
      CalendarWeekRule myCWR = myCI.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule;
      DayOfWeek myFirstDOW = myCI.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;

      // Displays the number of the current week relative to the beginning of the year.
      Console.WriteLine( "The CalendarWeekRule used for the en-US culture is {0}.", myCWR );
      Console.WriteLine( "The FirstDayOfWeek used for the en-US culture is {0}.", myFirstDOW );
      Console.WriteLine( "Therefore, the current week is Week {0} of the current year.", myCal.GetWeekOfYear( DateTime.Now, myCWR, myFirstDOW ));

      // Displays the total number of weeks in the current year.
      DateTime LastDay = new System.DateTime( DateTime.Now.Year, 12, 31 );
      Console.WriteLine( "There are {0} weeks in the current year ({1}).", myCal.GetWeekOfYear( LastDay, myCWR, myFirstDOW ), LastDay.Year );

   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
My.Computer.Info.InstalledUICulture.DateTimeFormat.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(yourDateHere, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, My.Computer.Info.InstalledUICulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek)
```

Something like this...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late, but since it came up in my search I thought I would throw a different solution in. This was a c# solution.

```
(int)(Math.Ceiling((decimal)startDate.Day / 7)) + (((new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, 1).DayOfWeek) > startDate.DayOfWeek) ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: This returns "5" for the date 29/12/2016 - it should return 52

Answer (score 1):

If you want the ISO 8601 Week Number, in which  weeks start with a monday, all weeks are seven days, and week 1 is the week containing the first thursday of the year, this may be a solution.

Since there doesn't seem to be a .Net-culture that yields the correct ISO-8601 week number, I'd rater bypass the built in week determination alltogether, and do the calculation manually, instead of atempting to correct a partially correct result.

What I ended up with is the following extension method:

```cs
public static int GetIso8601WeekNumber(this DateTime date)
{    var thursday = date.AddDays(3 - ((int)date.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7);
     return 1 + (thursday.DayOfYear - 1) / 7;
}
```

First of all, ((int)date.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7) determines the weekday number, 0=monday, 6=sunday.

date.AddDays(-((int)date.DayOfWeek + 6) % 7) determines the date of the monday preceiding the requested week number.

Three days later is the target thursday, which determines what year the week is in.

If you divide the (zero based) day-number within the year by seven (round down), you get the (zero based) week number in the year.

In c#, integer calculation results are round down implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

var cultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
            var calendar = cultureInfo.Calendar;

```
        var calendarWeekRule = cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule;
        var firstDayOfWeek = cultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek;
        var lastDayOfWeek = cultureInfo.LCID == 1033 //En-us
            ? DayOfWeek.Saturday
            : DayOfWeek.Sunday;

        var lastDayOfYear = new DateTime(date.Year, 12, 31);

         //Check if this is the last week in the year and it doesn`t occupy the whole week
        var weekNumber = calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date, calendarWeekRule, firstDayOfWeek);
        return weekNumber == 53 && lastDayOfYear.DayOfWeek != lastDayOfWeek 
               ? 1 
               : weekNumber;
```

It works well both for US and Russian cultures. ISO 8601 also will be correct, `cause Russian week starts at Monday.