# How do I find week numbers of a given date range in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I need to find the week numbers of a given date rage in C#.

Ex: date between 01/01/2014 and 14/01/2014 
     Week numbers are 1st,2nd and 3rd weeks, likewise.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you attempted? Can you provide example of your code?

Comment: Have a look at [How can I calculate/find the week-number of a given date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497586/how-can-i-calculate-find-the-week-number-of-a-given-date), will give you a starting point

Comment: Do you mean [ISO week number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)? May we see the code you have written that doesn't meet your needs?

Comment: @aaronmallen: There aren't *"example of code"* always !!

Comment: @huMptyduMpty I agree but the OP hasn't demonstrated any attempt at solving his own problem.

Comment: @aaronmallen: Of course!!

Comment: The link given is the right answer, and I just learned something. I love how there is a link to a question where the poster just asked pretty much the same question this poster did and gets marked up. We shouldn't be so quick to shoot down a post. I agree, no attempt to try but still we could help.

Comment: @Hammerstein I couldn't disagree with you more on this... SO shouldn't be a "I don't know how to do this, please do it for me" place. It should be a place where you learn real answers to real problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not the smartest way, but works!

```
  var d1 = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);
  var d2 = new DateTime(2014, 1, 14);
  var currentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
  var weeks = new List<int>();

  for (var dt = d1; dt < d2; dt =dt.AddDays(1))
   {
      var weekNo = currentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(
                            dt,
                            currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule,
                            currentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek);
       if(!weeks.Contains(weekNo))
         weeks.Add(weekNo);
  }
```

Comment: Wow, I did not know about CalendarWeekRule.  Also, you can calculate just the end points, and then enumerate between min and max.

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
public List<int> Weeks(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    List<int> weeks=new List<int>();
    var Week=(int)Math.Floor((double)start.DayOfYear/7.0); //starting week number
    for (DateTime t = start; t < end; t = t.AddDays(7))
    {
        weeks.Add(Week);
        Week++;
    }
    return weeks;
}
```

All this does is get the week of the start date, then loops through one week at a time until you get to the end date, incrementing the week and adding it to the list of weeks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's start with a simple, unoptimized example. We'll simply examine every date between those dates and check what week of the year it is.

We can do that with a simple loop:

```
var end = new DateTime(2014, 1, 14);
for (var date = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1); date <= end; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
}
```

This will simply loop over every day between two dates. Now we need to examine those days to determine their day of week. To do this you need to consider a few things: What is the first day of a week? Sunday? Monday? Are we assuming gregorian calendar?

For our example, let's assume the first day of the week is a Sunday and we are indeed using the Gregorian calendar. Then we will check each date, and keep a list of unique weeks of the year using a `HashSet`:

```
var weekNumber = new HashSet<int>();
var end = new DateTime(2014, 1, 14);
var calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
for (var date = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1); date <= end; date = date.AddDays(1))
{
    weekNumber.Add(calendar.GetWeekOfYear(date, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Sunday));
}
```

The `weekNumber` Hashset now contains the weeks of the year.

**Is this optimized?** No. It checks far more dates than it needs to, but the implementation is simple and *fast enough*. Optimizing can be done as a separate task.

Answer (score 0):

Easy.  Here's the code that determines the week of the year for a single date. This should get you going:

```
int WeekOfYear(DateTime date, DayOfWeek dayOfWeekStart) {
    //Find the first day of the year that's the start of week day.  If it's not 1/1,
    //then we have a first partial week.
    bool firstPartialWeek = false;
    DateTime firstFullWeekStart = new DateTime(date.Year, 1, 1);
    while(firstFullWeekStart.DayOfWeekDay != dayOfWeekStart) {
        firstFullWeekStart = firstOfWeek.AddDays(1);
        firstPartialWeek = true;
    }
    //Return the week by integer dividing the date difference by seven,
    //and adding in the potential first partial week
    return (firstPartialWeek ? 1 : 0) + ((date - firstFullWeekStart).TotalDays / 7);

}
```